# How to make the Access by Term module respect User Role permissions first?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I need [Access By Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/abt) (ABT) to respect the user Role permissions before considering the term relation between the user and the node.

**Scenario**
The user does not have permission to edit "Basic Page" content type but he is term related to a "Basic Page" node. He should not have permission to edit this page because his Role doesnt grant it, but as he is related to this node by a term, ABT grants him "update" permission.

Any ideas? Is it possible without patching it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Access By Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/abt). I've never used this module, but I have used [Workbench Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_access) which allows setting of an *Editorial Section* for content and people assigned to those sections to edit that content.

It sounds like you want a complex workflow better supported by [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench).

Comment: Workbench is to much for my actual structure, I don't need sections and new entities.. thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to "[How to make the permissions of a module more granular?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326/how-to-make-the-permissions-of-a-module-more-granular)", which explains how you can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for such kind of permission issues.

IMO this question here can be consider as another "use case" of it.

To also make the sample rule included there for this specific question, you'd probably only have to adapt the actual "url" to be intercepted.